# Insert all rows to a SQL Server table from a linked CSV file on a network drive in a frontend Access database

Tags: sql-server, csv, ms-access

I have a front end Access database with tables linked to a SQL Server database.

I want to insert the contents of a CSV file on a network drive that I have linked in the Access database to a SQL Server linked table in the Access database.

I have written the following code to insert the rows:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & Table1 & " SELECT * FROM " & Table1_CSV  
            db.Execute strSQL
```

This does the job but it takes about 20 minutes to run and I need to do the same thing for 9 other CSV files into linked SQL Server tables.

I have tried using BULK INSERT in a pass through query which I cant get working because the rows don't have a consistent row terminator(sometimes CR and other times CRLF).

Is there a more efficient way of doing this so this can be much quicker?  The task of importing the contents of the CSV files needs to be run every week.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Table1 and Table1_CSV are variables? How are they populated? Can do an UPDATE to replace CrLf with just Cr.

Comment: Table1 and Table1_csv are the names of the linked SQL Server table and linked CSV file on the network respectively.  The csv is copied to the network location daily and I'm hoping to populate Table1 by inserting all the rows of the CSV file.  I don't want to do any replacing of the row terminating characters in the CSV files because the 10 csv files (all very large) are copied to the network location daily and I am trying to update the linked SQL Server tables from these CSV files weekly.  Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest using VBA to do file I/O and fix the issues with Cr/CrLf on a copy of the files, and then use a stored procedure within SQL Server to do the bulk insert

Comment: I don't see how code works at all. Don't concatenate literal name strings, include within quote marks. Variables are concatenated.

Comment: I encountered similar problems in the past. Most of the time it's the network which is causing the issues. Try to download the Access Database as well as the CSV file to your local PC (ensure that you really use a local folder like "Download" for that) and test again